# WPF WebBrowser disable clicking & typing

Tags: c#, wpf, webbrowser-control

Is there a way to prevent users in clicking and typing in WPF WebBrowser? It appears to me that it is only possible to do this in WinForms.

Things that I've tried:

1. `browser.IsEnabled = false;` - didn't work, can still click (navigate) and type in text
2. `browser.Focusable = false;` - same
3. having overlay button, which would consume clicks and focus - WebBrowser is a special element, that is always on top of other elements
4. having another WebBrowser on top of the main one with blank page loaded and opacity set to 0% as an alternative to overlay button (3.) - WPF WebBrowsers do not properly handle opacity, didn't work
5. `browser_MouseDown` event with `e.Handled = true;` - the event is for some reason not called on mouse down

Is there something that I've missed or did wrong in my attempts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three events and Boolean did it for me.

```
    bool BrowserIsLoaded = false;

    private void Browser_LoadCompleted(object sender, NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        BrowserIsLoaded = true;
    }

    private void Browser_Navigating(object sender, NavigatingCancelEventArgs e)
    {
        if(BrowserIsLoaded)
            e.Cancel = true;
    }

    private void Browser_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (BrowserIsLoaded)
            e.Handled = true;
    }
```

When the browser has finished loading it triggers the LoadCompleted event.  Set a Boolean then check that when trying to navigate to a new page when they try to type in a box.

If you don't want to use your own Boolean (I used it for other things so it made sense to me) you can just ask the browser if it's loaded when ever you need it:

```
    private void Browser_Navigating(object sender, NavigatingCancelEventArgs e)
    {
         WebBrowser wb = (WebBrowser)sender;
         if(wb.IsLoaded)
         {
              e.Cancel = true;
         }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. Any comments on why KeyDown works, but MouseDown doesn't?